# Не вижу кода программы Visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, ide

Не вижу кода программы Visual studio 2019. Очищал кэш - не помогает.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При этом программа работает

Comment: выберите файл в обозревателе решений справа

Answer (score 1):

Справа от рабочей области есть окно "обозреватель решений". Там древовидный список, который нужно раскрыть и выбрать нужный вам файл с текстом программы.